# Simple apache2 redirect from one domain to another

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, redirect, url

What I want to do is the following:

My domain xy.example.com no longer exists. Thus I want to do a simple redirect to the new domain abc.example.com. It should be a redirect, that also works when someone types in the browser bar http://xy.example.com/team.php - than it shoul redirect to http://abc.example.com/team.php

I've already tried a few things, but it didn't really work. What do I have to put in the Apache 2 config?

Comment: A late comment. if xy.example.com does not *exist* anymore meaning there is no ip-adress for xy.example.com, nobody will go anywhere when they type that in the browser. The domain must exist before anyone can go there to be redirected. It's like putting a physical answering machine on your old telephone line giving your new number, then disconnecting the line.

Comment: For ISPConfig redirect, see https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/redirecting-a-domain-to-external-website.56389/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use the [RedirectPermanent](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) directive to redirect the client to your new URL.

Just create a very simple VirtualHost for the old domain in which you redirect it to the new domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xy.example.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://abc.example.com/
    # optionally add an AccessLog directive for
    # logging the requests and do some statistics
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Actually not so simple because you might need to redir both http and https and that becomes two VH. And also you need to add ssl config... So probably easier to use mod_rewrite.

Comment: @Nux That wasn't asked, so it wasn't answered. 

Answer (score 17):

Create or edit a `.htaccess` inside your `DocumentRoot`. Add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Additionally I would change the `ServerName` directive to the new domain and leave a `ServerAlias` with the old domain.

```
ServerName abc.example.com
ServerAlias xy.example.com
```

Comment: I cant see how this would work on its own. A RedirectCond !^xy.example.com$ is required to prevent a forwarding loop.

Comment: The ServerAlias solution would not work with HTTPS, if a certificate for `abc.example.com` is used. Upon connecting to `https://xy.example.com` the browser would display a certificate error and ask user confirmation to continue. Also it is not a "redirection" to `abc.example.com`, because the browser location URL would not be changed, but kept as `xy.example.com`.

Comment: $1 by default contains the index path /. So we should remove /. 
http://abc.example.com$1

Answer (score 2):

VH is OK if you can do it, but not really a drop-in solution.

I prefer using `If`:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'old.example.com'">
    Redirect "/" "https://new.example.com/"
</If>
```

This is something you could use in the same place you define ServerAlias. And should work fine in multi-tenant environment.

Comment: This is neat! Does it work in the .htaccess too?

Comment: Hm... Haven't tried, but both directives are allowed in hta, so should work. See:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: Do note that using hta makes requests a bit slower. Not much, but generally config is conidered faster.

Comment: If this works with .htaccess - it is a nice solution for a multisite in a shared host environment. Thanks